# Hibernate cache(TypeHelper.assemble, CacheEntry.assemble)

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, caching

I add a varchar(15) in table Service,
restart tomcat, call api and than this error occures:

```
at-------------:org.hibernate.type.TypeHelper.assemble(TypeHelper.java:110)
at-------------:org.hibernate.cache.entry.CacheEntry.assemble(CacheEntry.java:117)
at-------------:org.hibernate.cache.entry.CacheEntry.assemble(CacheEntry.java:104)
at-------------:org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.assembleCacheEntry(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:651)
at-------------:org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.assembleCacheEntry(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:651)
at-------------:org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromSecondLevelCache(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:605)
at-------------:org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:459)
at-------------:org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:227)
at-------------:org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:285)
at-------------:org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:152)
at-------------:org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1090)
at-------------:org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:1005)
at-------------:org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:998)
at-------------:org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$1.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:519)
at-------------:org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:406)
at-------------:org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
at-------------:org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.get(HibernateTemplate.java:512)
at-------------:org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.get(HibernateTemplate.java:506)
at-------------:org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateOperations$get.call(Unknown Source)
at-------------:org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateGormStaticApi.get(HibernateGormEnhancer.groovy:182)
```

This is my hibernate config:

```
 hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache = true
 hibernate.cache.use_query_cache = true
 hibernate.cache.provider_class = com.googlecode.hibernate.memcached.MemcachedCacheProvider
 hibernate.connection.release_mode = after_statement
 hibernate.memcached.servers = localhost:11213
```

Can anyone please help me?